# How to add an existing dictionary as a nested dictionary to an already existing dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In python3, I have 2 dictionaries, dict1 and dict2 that are both populated with key/value pairs. I want to create a new dictionary dict3 and add both dict1 and dict2 as nested dictionaries to it. I cant BELIEVE how much time Ive wasted trying to google a solution. I find tutorial after tutorial about how to create nested dictionaries from scratch but nothing about adding an existing dictionary nested to another dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by nested dictionaries? What do you want to be the keys of `dict3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
dict1={1:2,3:4}
dict2={5:6,7:8}
dict3=dict(list(dict1.items())+[('dict2', dict2)])

print(dict3)
```

Output:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4, 'dict2': {5: 6, 7: 8}}
```

Or if you want to add the two dictionary:

```
dict1={1:2,3:4}
dict2={5:6,7:8}
dict3=dict([('dict1', dict1)]+[('dict2', dict2)])

print(dict3)
#Output:
#{'dict1': {1: 2, 3: 4}, 'dict2': {5: 6, 7: 8}}
```

Another ways:

```
#first scenario
dict1={1:2,3:4}
dict2={5:6,7:8}
dict3={**dict1}
dict3.update({'dict2':dict2})
print(dict3)
#Output:
#{1: 2, 3: 4, 'dict2': {5: 6, 7: 8}}

#second scenario
dict1={1:2,3:4}
dict2={5:6,7:8}
dict3={}
dict3.update({'dict1':dict1,'dict2':dict2})
print(dict3)
#Output:
#{'dict1': {1: 2, 3: 4}, 'dict2': {5: 6, 7: 8}}
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! This is EXACTLY the information that has eluded me. I certainly appreciate the different examples!